How to automatically install VMs using virt-manager?
Tech newbie here.
I found myself to be using VMs a lot as of late and I don't think creating VMs through GUI is the most intuitive way, especially when you have to specify different paths to directories where ISO file is located etc.
I was following this guide https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/virtualization-getting-started/
In hopes of finding a solution to my problem.
Initially, I used this command:
sudo virt-install --name Fedora39 
--description 'Fedora 39 Workstation' 
--ram 8096 
--vcpus 6 
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Fedora-Workstation-39/Fedora-Workstation-39-20180518.0.x86_64.qcow2,size=20 
--os-type linux 
--os-variant fedora38 
--network bridge=virbr0 
--graphics vnc,listen=127.0.0.1,port=5901 
--cdrom /var/lib/libvirt/images/Fedora-Workstation-39/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-39-1.5.iso 
--noautoconsole
But now I have to create a kickstart file for full OS automation.
At this point, I have no idea how do I get started and other guides on kickstart files seem too complex.
My question is, do I really need to use kickstart files in my case and if so, how do I do that.
Thank you.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f36/install-guide/advanced/Kickstart_Installations/
